# Sacar 0 con count() Mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo 2 tablas:

```
-Tabla departamentos con 1 campo(Nombre_Depart) y 3 inserts:
Comercio,Informatica,Centro.

Tabla Usuarios con 2 campos(Nombre,departamento) y 3 inserts:
Edu en informatica.
Jaime en informatica.
Conserje en centro.
```

Quiero sacar en una tabla EL TOTAL de personas que pertenecen a los departamentos y su nombre.

```
SELECT count(Nombre_Depart),Departamento
from usuarios,departamentos
where departamentos.Nombre_Depart=usuarios.Departamento 
GROUP BY Nombre_Depart
```

El problema es que el departamento de comercio no lo muestra porque en la tabla usuarios nadie está en ese departamento.
¿Qué tengo qué hacer para que aparezca un 0 -- Comercio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que hacer un left join.

```
SELECT d.Nombre_Depart, Count(u.nombre)
from departamentos d
left join usuarios u
on d.Nombre_Depart=u.Departamento 
GROUP BY d.Nombre_Depart
```

Además, deberías normalizar tus tablas de forma que en la tabla de usuarios almacenes el id del departamento y no su nombre, de manera que esta sería la forma correcta:

```
SELECT d.Nombre_Depart, Count(u.nombre)
from departamentos d
left join usuarios u
on d.id =u.id_Departamento 
GROUP BY d.Nombre_Depart
```

**EDIT: Corregido la devolución del Count()**

Comment: Sin nvl me dice que en comercio hay 1 >>mal

y con nvl 
MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1305 - FUNCTION macs.nvl does not exist
he probado IFNULL sigue poniendo 1

Comment: Si, perdona, eso es para Oracle. Lo edito

Comment: con IFNULL saca 1 en comercio =((

Comment: Ahora si, lo he probado. Tirar de memoria a veces no es bueno.... ;). Sacaba 1 porque te había puesto un * en el count, y contaba el registro del departamento. Si se cambia por un campo de la tabla que tiene los nulos sacará 0. Lo tienes en la respuesta.

Comment: Ahora sí, muchas gracias.

Comment: Un placer haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizar un left join entre las dos tablas para que no te excluya los que no tienen asociacion [LEFT JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp).

```
SELECT count(Nombre_Depart),Departamento
from usuarios LEFT JOIN Departamento ON Departamento.Nombre_Depart = usuarios.departamento 
GROUP BY Nombre_Depart
```